# Can a component type map to a Entity type in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

Suppose i have a class Address which is dependent upon User class.
Address is Component type.
Can Address class contain reference to anyother entity say Country.

if yes?

Are all 4 relations possible with Address and country

one-to-one

many-to-one

many-to-many

one-to-many

If possible please explain with some JPA annotation

Answer (score 3):

[Updated]  Components are "stand-alone values" or "value objects". There *is* partial support for outbound relationships, and inbound relationships with the `mappedBy` specification, but 'component' is not a first-class 'entity'.

Many persistence features -- querying, caching, locking, bulk loading & session-control features are all primarily designed at the 'entity' level. Beyond a certain point, there will be limitations with what you can do with a 'component'.. whether you will encounter such limitations depends on how deep you go.

But actually modelling your scenario, the utility of a `Country` table with foreign-keys to it is limited. So probably most correct design is to keep Address.Country denormalized and support it with an auto-complete.

The reason this is the preferred approach:

When countries do change their names or borders -- it is typically not in a "relationally normalized" way. For example, Yugoslavia -> Croatia, Serbia, Montenegro. Sudan -> Sudan, South Sudan. Disputed borders shift & countries break up, but actually being able to just rename one well-identified country is not common.

Compare with people: People have stable identity & can change their name/address, but countries don't have this in a very useful way.

Comment: I came across 
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html
                              
here its clearly visible that we can map one-to-one relation from a component type to entity type.
So i believe what you told is not correct.

Comment: Thanks for the link, David.. it looks like support for bi-directional assocs & "relating back" is better than it used to be (though there may be some limitations). I'd still keep Country as a plain text field -- it's better modelling & design, regardless of the technical aspect of 'whether you could' normalize it.